# how to run specific test from php-src testsuite?

Tags: php

How do I run just a specific test from the [php-src](https://github.com/php/php-src) testsuite? For example if I only want to run the [/ext/standard/tests/file/file_variation6.phpt](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/tests/file/file_variation6.phpt) test? the invocation

```
make TEST_PHP_ARGS=-j4 test
```

run all the tests, which is kind of overkill when i only have a problem with 1 specific test ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to only run that specific test, invoke

```
sapi/cli/php run-tests.php -P {test-path}
```

for example:

```
$ sapi/cli/php run-tests.php -P ext/standard/tests/file/file_variation6.phpt

=====================================================================
PHP         : /home/hans/projects/php-src/sapi/cli/php 
PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 8.2.0-dev
ZEND_VERSION: 4.2.0-dev
PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux devad22 5.4.0-122-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 15:00:31 UTC 2022 x86_64
INI actual  : /home/hans/projects/php-src
More .INIs  :  
---------------------------------------------------------------------
PHP         : /home/hans/projects/php-src/sapi/cgi/php-cgi 
PHP_SAPI    : cgi-fcgi
PHP_VERSION : 8.2.0-dev
ZEND_VERSION: 4.2.0-dev
PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux devad22 5.4.0-122-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 15:00:31 UTC 2022 x86_64
INI actual  : /home/hans/projects/php-src
More .INIs  : 
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
PHP         : /home/hans/projects/php-src/sapi/phpdbg/phpdbg 
PHP_SAPI    : phpdbg
PHP_VERSION : 8.2.0-dev
ZEND_VERSION: 4.2.0-dev
PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux devad22 5.4.0-122-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 22 15:00:31 UTC 2022 x86_64
INI actual  : /home/hans/projects/php-src
More .INIs  : 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
CWD         : /home/hans/projects/php-src
Extra dirs  : 
VALGRIND    : Not used
=====================================================================
Running selected tests.
FAIL file() with a range of integer flag values [ext/standard/tests/file/file_variation6.phpt] 
=====================================================================
Number of tests :    1                 1
Tests skipped   :    0 (  0.0%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :    1 (100.0%) (100.0%)
Tests passed    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :    0 seconds
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
file() with a range of integer flag values [ext/standard/tests/file/file_variation6.phpt]
=====================================================================
```

found that info on https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/tests/running_the_test_suite.html :)